# How to enable CORS in Blazor Static Web App?

Tags: c#, cors, blazor, dotnet-httpclient, azure-static-web-app

I have tried every other ways to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *` in my Blazor Static Web App.

I follow this documentation [Configure Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration) first to set `globalHeaders`. It isn't working.

And I try to add Cors in builder services. It isn't working too.

```
        builder.Services.AddScoped (sp => new HttpClient 
        { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["API_Prefix"] ??
        builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        builder.Services.AddCors(options => 
        { options.AddPolicy(name: policyName,
                  builder =>
                  { builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5000") // specifying the allowed origin
                        .WithMethods("GET") // defining the allowed HTTP method
                        .AllowAnyHeader(); // allowing any header to be sent
                  });
        }); 
        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

And I tried it also in individual `HttpClient` request in the following.

```
        // create request object
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);

        // add custom http header
        request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");

        // send request
        var httpResponse = await Http.SendAsync(request);
```

I had used this tutorial to create [Blazor Static Web App].[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-blazor)

This is the error I got in the browser's console. [image: CORS error]].[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u478y.png)

What am I missing to set the correct configuration?

Comment: Even though I can get the JSON response in plain browser's request, I couldn't do it in my app. Here is the link https://dev.to/api/articles?username=zawhtut to get the JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Restrict Domain consumption of services by CORS browser restriction. But when you hit the service service will get executed but the response wont captured in browser side. By adding following code in **API program.cs** will allow specific Domains

```
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("http://192.168.10.127",
                            "https://localhost:5000",
                            "https://localhost:5001")
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

app.UseCors();
```

To allow from any Domain follow below code

```
app.UseCors(options => options.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
```